# Add Removed Subview Swift 3 iOS

Tags: ios, swift3, addsubview

In a self.view there is a subview(tempView) which I am removing from superview but when I am trying to add that back it is not showing in the view. while checking the frame I found that their frame is correct but the view is not visible. Below is the code for removing my view from superview and adding it back.

```
if(self.view.subviews.contains(self.tempView))
{
    self.tempView.removeFromSuperview()
}
else
{
    self.view.addSubview(self.tempView)
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront:self.tempView)
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Comment: you still need to re-set the frame

Comment: if you remove view from superview then U have to allocate and reframe it again to add

Comment: Not necessary if the object of the view is set to Strong. Only if its weak it will lose its properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try set translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=true

```
if(self.view.subviews.contains(self.tempView))
{
    self.tempView.removeFromSuperview()
}
else
{
    self.tempView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints=true
    self.view.addSubview(self.tempView)
    self.view.bringSubview(toFront:self.tempView)
}
```